# Firefox addon: return HTML from custom protocol handler?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to return document content from a custom protocol handler.

I can redirect to a URL's fine, but I can't return the document body myself.

```
newChannel: function(aURI)
{
  var ioservice = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService);
  var resource = aURI.spec.split(":")[1];
  var wheretogo = WhereToGo(resource);
  var uri = ioservice.newURI(wheretogo, null, null);
  if (uri) {
    var channel = ioservice.newChannelFromURI(uri, null).QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
    return channel;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
},
classDescription: "Protocol Handler",
contractID: "@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=myproto",
classID: Components.ID('{xxxx}'),
QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIProtocolHandler])
```

I've tried accessing the window from within the wheretogo method:

```
var ww = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"]
               .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowWatcher);
var win = ww.activeWindow.document.innerHTML = 'test';
```

But this doesn't do anything (no error either).

I also tried:

```
 return "data:text/html,test";
```

But this too doesn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `data:` URI should be the simplest approach but you cannot simply return a string - the method `newChannel` has to return a channel. The following should work:

```
newChannel: function(aURI)
{
  var htmlData = "test";
  var ioservice = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService);
  var uri = ioservice.newURI("data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(htmlData),
                             null, null);
  var channel = ioservice.newChannelFromURI(uri);
  return channel;
},
```

Some notes:

- [nsIIOService.newChannelFromURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIIOService#newChannelFromURI%28%29) takes only one parameter (your code gave it two).
- `newChannel` cannot return a boolean, it has to return `null` or (better) throw an exception, e.g. `throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED`.
- You don't need `QueryInterface`, `newChannel` can return any channel - not necessarily an HTTP channel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One more question; is it possible to redirect in this way? I notice that my URL now shows as bla:xyz but in certain cases I need to redirect to external sites. This works, but the URL doesn't update and if the HTML page does not use full URLs (domain name included) for CSS/JS those are not loaded.

Comment: Never mind, its done with loadFlags: var loadFlags = channel.loadFlags;
      loadFlags |= Components.interfaces.nsIChannel.LOAD_REPLACE;
      channel.loadFlags = loadFlags;